# URL in post request (js)

Tags: javascript, php, post

I have a form:

```
    <form>
        <input id = "sendLink" type = "text" placeholder = "insert a link here">
    </form>
```

Then i trying to send data (it's a url (string) like http://sameURL.com) :

```
        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://host:8453/page.htm', true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.send($link);
```

But on server side i receive a 'splitted' post body:

```
"headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    ...
    more headers here
    ...
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
},
"httpVersion": "1.1",
"method": "POST",
"post": {
    "http://sameURL.com": ""
},
"postRaw": "http://sameURL.com",
"url": "/page.htm"
```

}

Why i got

"http://sameURL.com": ""

in post body instead of

"http://sameURL.com"

? Thank you. I need request without additional colon and "".
I should work only with "http://sameURL.com" string.

**UPD 1**

Testing purpose: 
$link = "https://google.com?q1=asdf?q2=ddd?q3=ppp";

In that case we got:

```
"post": {
        "https://google.com?q1": "asdf?q2=ddd?q3=ppp"
},
"postRaw": "https://google.com?q1=asdf?q2=ddd?q3=ppp",
```

Comment: Can you provide the dynamic initialization of the `$link` variable? I'm guessing that you are sending JSON with only 1 key in it and no values. Thus, when you decode it in PHP, accessing `arr['http://sameURL.com']` will return an empty string.

Comment: I got the same result with setting of the string manually: $link = "https://google.com";. And on server :  "post": {         "https://google.com":  ""    },

Comment: damned parser in commentaries adds new characters and removes same symbols like h t t p. Please look at the UPD1 section in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a header saying the data is form encoded, so the server is expecting key/value pairs.

I think you should try plain instead [What is the difference between form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded and raw in the Postman Chrome application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723467/what-is-the-difference-between-form-data-x-www-form-urlencoded-and-raw-in-the-p)

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
```

Comment: Thank you! That's i need. Now post is onse single row : "post": "https://google.com?q1=asdf?q2=ddd?q3=ppp",

Comment: @sameuser Would you mind marking it as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are not sending your data properly.

Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

**UDP 1:**

```
"https://google.com?q1": "asdf?q2=ddd?q3=ppp"
```

You have no `&` symbols to send more than one key value pair. Also, read up on how data is typically sent and received in these requests.

If I were you, I would do the following:

```
$link = "link=https://google.com&q1=asdf&q2=ddd&q3=ppp";
```

I haven't tested it, but it should result in:

```
"post": {
    "link": "https://google.com,
    "q1"  : "asdf",
    "q2"  : "ddd",
    "q3"  : "ppp"
}
```

**Original Question**

In the case of your original url:

```
$link = "link=http://sameURL.com";
```

Which would show:

```
"post": {
    "link": "http://sameURL.com"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, cant vote for your question, because min 15 reputation is needed. :(