# how to convert curl command into postman

Tags: curl, postman, mail-server

I am going to use mailgun api.

Here is the cRUL command working in terminal properly.

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-...' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/DomainName/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <mailgun@DomainName>' \
    -F to=me@outlook.com \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
```

I can't make sense how I can run this command using Postman.

I tried to import cURL command into Postman but it doesn't import **api:key**. I really can't understand how I can import this api key into Postman to run the api properly.

Please help me to run this command using Postman.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried placing it in the headers as a key and value pair?

Comment: @Ray. Yes, I tried. But it doesn't work for me. :(

Answer (score 2):

For whoever wants to create the Postman request manually:

The `--user` (or `-u`) translates in Postman into **Basic Auth** *Username* and *Password* fields, which you find under the **Authorization** request nav option:

[image]

The `-F` (for form params) you add under **Body** request nav option, with *x-www-form-urlencoded* or *form-data* selected (if not sure which, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723467/what-is-the-difference-between-form-data-x-www-form-urlencoded-and-raw-in-the-p) question):

[image]

More on `curl` options [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/curl.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Try importing it like this

```
curl https://api:key@api.mailgun.net/v3/DomainName/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <mailgun@DomainName>' \
    -F to=me@outlook.com \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
```