# Post method works in raw but not in x-www-form-urlencoded POSTMAN

Tags: php, post, postman

This might be stupid but I hope you guys could enlighten me why this works

[Image: POST using RAW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBiJo.png)
But using x-www-form-urlencoded makes all value null

[Image: POST using x-www-form urlencoded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEZny.png)

here's the php side

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/mediapp/");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// files needed to connect to database
include_once 'config/database.php';
include_once 'Objects/user.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// instantiate user object
$user = new User($db);

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

I also tried changing the content type but results are still the same. Am I not using POSTMAN properly, do I need to change something in php side? I need it to also work with x-www-form-url-encoded

Comment: FWIW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723467/what-is-the-difference-between-form-data-x-www-form-urlencoded-and-raw-in-the-p

Comment: Your form isn't submitting json.  Try `$data = $_POST`

Comment: The request must contain `Content-type: application/json` instead of `Content-type: aplication/x-www-form-url-encoded` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

`x-www-form-urlencoded` will send the body like

```
firstname=mikey&lastname=dalisay
```

that why `json_decode()` return null, use `parse_str` to convert it to PHP object

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $data);
var_dump($data);
echo $data['firstname'];
```

if you want to accept both `raw` and `x-www-form-urlencoded` you can write like

```
$reqBody = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($reqBody);
if(!$data){
  parse_str($reqBody, $data);
}
```

Comment: You could simply check the content type header from the request then call json_decode or parse_str depending on content type, or throw an error if any other content type is encountered.

Comment: still returns null

Comment: @jtyg it null when you print `$data` or response from database?