# What does UrlEncodedFormEntity do in Apache HttpClient 4?

Tags: java, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x, urlencode

If you want to do an HTTP Post with parameters and have it be sent with a content type of "x-www-form-urlencoded" then the way to do that in Apache HTTP Client 3 is...

```
    HttpMethod method = new PostMethod(myUrl)

    method.setParams(mp)
    method.addParameter("user_name", username)
    method.addParameter("password", password)

    method.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

    int responseCode = httpClient.executeMethod(method)
```

But Apache HTTP Client 4 introduced the UrlEncodedFormEntity object, so the new way of doing the same there is...

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", username));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));;

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

What purpose does this UrlEncodedFormEntity object serve other than setting the content type to "x-www-form-urlencoded"?

The [docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html) say it creates an "An entity composed of a list of url-encoded pairs", but can't that be done just by setting the content type?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data

Comment: Also you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723467/what-is-the-difference-between-form-data-x-www-form-urlencoded-and-raw-in-the-p/36452270

Answer (score 2):

The `HttpEntity` interface is the top-level interface controlling how the body of the request/response is handled. In this case, you're using a `UrlEncodedFormEntity` which knows how to encode the parameters and output them in the required format.

Comment: so UrlEncodedFormEntity will Url encode the key and value of the BasicNameValuePair I supply to it?