# Not receiving form-data in PATCH method in express (Node)

Tags: node.js, body-parser

Posting data to an endpoint which is working fine when I select `raw` and send json.

I am not receiving anything when I select `form-data`. I have already defined them in my `server.js`.

server.js config:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.static('app/uploaded'));
// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Here is the postman request.

[image]

Comment: are you sending a POST request? it says PATCH there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman Chrome: What is the difference between form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded and raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723467/postman-chrome-what-is-the-difference-between-form-data-x-www-form-urlencoded)  I think you want x-form-urlencoded.

Comment: @d9ngle my bad, updated it

Comment: @O.Jones x-form-urlencoded is working fine.  I will be sending files over this request so I need to test using form-data

Answer (score 3):

hi for parsing different form of data you have to add different middleware to access it

here is the code for parsing response:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
var app = express();

// for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

// for parsing application/xwww-
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
//form-urlencoded

// for parsing multipart/form-data
app.use(upload.array());
```

refer [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_form_data.htm) doc for more detail documentation of body-parser with form data

let me know if its help

Comment: Exactly, To handle multipart form-data, express needs `multer`

Comment: @O.Jones it's already in the class where form-data is received

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo yes but could you please try this because sometimes you have to pass it as a middleware