# How to read an image sent in body of req in falcon

Tags: falconframework

Sending jpg image in body of POST, using postman to do so:

[image]

Reading it with
**image_text_similarity.py:**

```
import json
class ImageTextSimilarity():
    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        image_raw = json.loads(req.stream.read())
```

which errors out with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dario/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/home/dario/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 175, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "falcon/api.py", line 274, in falcon.api.API.__call__
  File "falcon/api.py", line 269, in falcon.api.API.__call__
  File "/home/dario/ImageTextSimilarityApp/image_text_similarity.py", line 95, in on_post
    image_raw = json.loads(req.stream.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 349, in loads
    s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

### How do we read the image from the body of the POST request?

Rest of the code is
**image_similarity_app.py:**

```
import falcon
from image_text_similarity import ImageTextSimilarity

api = application = falcon.API()
api.req_options.auto_parse_form_urlencoded = True
image_text_similarity_object = ImageTextSimilarity()
api.add_route('/image_text_similarity', image_text_similarity_object)
```

And starting the service with `gunicorn image_similarity_app`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert at Postman, but it appears that by choosing *binary*, you are sending your JPEG image data as the request body: [Postman Chrome: What is the difference between form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded and raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723467/postman-chrome-what-is-the-difference-between-form-data-x-www-form-urlencoded)

In Falcon, you can simply read the request payload as

```py
jpeg_data = req.stream.read()
```

(Note that on some app servers such as the stdlib's `wsgiref.simple_server`, you may need to use the safe [`Request.bounded_stream`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/request_and_response_wsgi.html#falcon.Request.bounded_stream) wrapper.)

See also Falcon's [WSGI](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/tutorial.html) and [ASGI tutorials](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/tutorial-asgi.html#tutorial-asgi) for inspiration; they use are very related topic (building an image service) to illustrate the basic concepts of the framework. You'll find examples how to handle RESTful image resources: upload, convert, store, list, serve, cache etc.